# Anyone got the Ace editor to work from Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I would like to embed the [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/) JavaScript editor in a Visualforce page. One problem is that even the minified source trees are quite large so have to be "chopped" down to fit within the 5M static resource limit.

But from an hour of experimentation, it is looking like referenced JavaScript components, such as the theme, don't load correctly from the (zipped) static resource.

Has anyone got Ace to work in a Visualforce page?